# Visualization of open balls for different metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces, visualization

I've got a lot of problems imagining how open balls look like in metric spaces. This prevents me getting better insight in some proofs and exercises.

An example is the $d_1$-metric defined as follows: $$d_1(x,y) = \frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|} (x,y \in \mathbb{R})$$
and the $d_2$-metric on a function space $C([0,1])$:
$$d_{\infty}(f,g) = sup\{|f(t) - g(t)| | t \in [0,1]\}  \  \ \  (f,g \in C([0,1]).$$
For the $d_1$-metric an open ball centered at $x$ and radius $r>0$ is
$$ B_1(x,r) = \begin{cases}\mathbb{R}&\text{if $r \geq1$}\\ \left]x - \frac{r}{1-r} , x + \frac{r}{1-r} \right[ \hspace{10mm}\text{if $r < 1$}\end{cases}$$
I don't quite see how the open ball for $r \geq 1$ can be $\mathbb{R}$.

For the $d_{\infty}$-metric I have an idea on how to draw it in two dimensions, but I'm not sure. Can anyone enlighten this for me (maybe in 3 dimensions)? Also, how do you imagine it? Is there some simple trick to 'see' it, maybe by looking at some critical points?

Comment: If $0<r<1$ then  $d_1(x,y)<r\iff |x-y|<r/(1-r)=S(r)$ so  the open ball centered at $x,$ of radius $r,$ is the  interval $(x-S(r),x+S(r)).$.... $S(r)$ can be any member of $\Bbb R^+,$ depending on $r.$  And any  $d_1$ open ball of radius $1$ or more is the whole space. The only difference between the set of open $d_1$ balls and the set of open balls of the usual metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ is that $\Bbb R$ is an open ball of $d_1.$

Comment: An open $d_1$ ball of radius $r$ is $\Bbb R$ when $ r\geq 1$ because  $d_1(x,y)<1$ for all $x,y\in \Bbb R.$

Comment: How does is follow from $d_1(x,y) <1 $ that the open ball is $\mathbb{R}$ when $r \geq 1$? To me it seems just that for $x \in \mathbb{R} ,y \in ]x-1,x+1[$ for every $y$.

Comment: If $r\geq 1 $ and some $y\in \Bbb R $  $ didn't $ belong to $B_{d_1}(x,r)=\{y:d_1(x,y)<r\}, $ it would be necessary that $d_1(x,y)\geq r\geq 1.$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$d_1(x,y) = \frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}<1  (x,y \in \mathbb{R})$$

Therefore if $r>1$ every point $y\in \mathbb {R}$ satisfies  $$d_1(x,y)<r$$

Thus the open ball centered at $x$ with radius $r$ contains all of the real line.

The open balls for $d_\infty $ metric are ribbons or tubes around the central function depending on the dimension.